# pointer to struct. Segmentation fault on read value of member

Tags: c, linux, pointers, memory, struct

I'm trying to map some area of the physical memory and then put it in struct. Mapping is OK and the assignment is OK. ( I think so, because there is no segmentation fault.) The problem is when I try to read some value from the struct.

My struct is something like this:

```
struct some_struct {
    unsigned long a;
    unsigned long b;
    unsigned long c;
    unsigned long d;
    unsigned long e;
    unsigned long f;
};
```

Then I map the memory:

```
void *pc = (void *) mmap(0, PageSize * 2, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, addr_start);
```

Don't look too closely at the parameters. I'm 100% sure that this works fine. After that I do this:

```
struct some_struct *ptr = ((struct some_struct *)(pc + some_offset));
```

Then I try:

```
printf("DDR[%p] -> 0x%x\n", &(ptr->a));
```

And I get the address of the member. It points at physical address in the memory. But the following gets me segmentation fault:

```
printf("DDR[%p] -> 0x%x\n", &(ptr->a), ptr->a);
```

I'm not sure if I have to use physical of virtual address when I assign the struct. Or I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: Have you tried Valgrind?

Comment: By the way, the first `printf` call leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), you tell `printf` to print two things, but provide only one thing to print. Also, when printing pointers you should really cast them to `void *`.

Comment: Lastly, the [`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) function is already declared to return `void *`, so no need to cast the return value.

Comment: @Joachim `some_offset` doesn't necessarily have to be a multiple of `sizeof(some_struct)` because the file is not necessarily just an array of `some_struct`. There could be arbitrary stuff in there. _But `some_offset` must be less than `PageSize * 2 - sizeof(some_struct)`._

Comment: OK guys, as usual I get the solution the minute I write the question. When I assign the pointer to the structure I'm using physical memory address, when I should use the the virtual one returned by the mmap function.

Comment: Maybe a moot point, but I'm not sure why you keep going on about physical addresses. Every address involved here is virtual. Maybe you consider offsets into the file to be physical addresses? An offset is different than a physical address; in fact, the OS does not expose physical addresses to processes for lots of very good reasons.

Comment: @SchighSchagh Ah your right

Comment: You did not check the return value you get from mmap(). It could be `(void*)-1` ... Note : `&(p->a)` does not dereference the pointer, it just adds thee offset (0). `p->a` does dereference the pointer.

Comment: `pc + offset` is illegal, void pointers cannot have arithmetic done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough of your code to give a full help.

I can provide only possible problems, that you can have in your code:

From `man mmap`:

1) If you want to read and write, you should have `open("./file.txt", O_RDWR);` in your code.

```
The prot argument describes the desired memory protection of the mapping 
(and must not conflict with the open mode of the file).
```

2) You offset `must` be `k*sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)`.
On my system, for example, the page size is `4096`. So your `addr_start` must be like `4*4096`, but not like `12` or an any arbitrary number.

```
offset must be a multiple of the page size as returned by sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)
```

3) Compile your code with all warnings enabled and see what compiler will write to you. If you use `gcc`, than add `-Wall` flag. You already have an undefined behavior in your `printf` statement (this was already mentioned in the comments) and with `-Wall` compiler will tell you about it.

4) If you still want compile without `-Wall` flag, then ensure that you have all needed headers included to your program. I've included:

```
//mmap
#include <sys/mman.h>
//printf
#include <stdio.h>
//open
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
//sysconf
#include <unistd.h>
```

Hope this will help.

P.S. I've saw that you have solved your problem already just after I've wrote this post (but I still do not understand your problem). So I just leave this in case anyone other fill have similar behavior, but the different problem.